# Not returning a null list but also not returning an immutable empty one and alternative approaches

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, null-object-pattern

I have a method that returns a `List`.
E.g.
`List<Foo> getItems(Bar bar, X x)`

I don't want the method to return `null` to avoid null pointer exception and do something like:

```
List<Foo> getItems(Bar bar, X x) {
   if(!bar.conditionA() || !x.conditionB()) {
     return new ArrayList<>();  
   }
}
```

Note that the calling code uses the returning list to merge it with other lists.
E.g.

```
List<Foo> result = getItems(bar, x);
result.addAll(getFoo());  
result.addAll(getAll());  
result.addAll(getItems(bar, x));  
etc
```

My question is the following: from what I have seen some think that it is more optimal to return e.g. `Collections.emptyList()` to avoid instantiating a new list, but the issue is that if I change to follow that then the calling code becomes I think more complicated because the `Collections.emptyList()` is immutable so the calling code should be:

```
List<Foo> result = getItems(bar, x);
if(!result.isEmpty()) {
   result.addAll(getFoo());  
   result.addAll(getAll());
 }  
etc
```

which to me seems a bit more tedius.

Is there another way to handle both approaches nice?

Comment: Returning an immutable list shouldn't be a problem since we merge in a mutable `ArrayList`. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/SahbCe).

Comment: There is, of course, the possibility to transform all those lists into streams, concatenate the streams and then collect to a list. But this seems over-engineered and gets messy fast. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/GhMKMO)

Comment: @Turing85: Good point. I updated my post. I messed up the example

Comment: Replace `List<Foo> result = getItems(bar, x);` with `ArrayList<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>(getitems(bar, x));` and you're good to go.

Comment: If the caller is going to modify the list, then it makes no sense to "avoid instantiating a new list". The only question is whether you're instantiating it in the caller or within `getItems()`. The former is better practice.

Comment: @root: `instantiating it in the caller` what do you mean by this? What Turing85 mentions? Also why is it better practice so I understand it better?

Comment: Yes, I mean what @Turing85 mentions. And it's better practice precisely because the function can return immutable objects if it wants to, and new objects get instantiated only if the caller needs new instances.